# Connect Salesforce with DBeaver Salesforce CDP

Tags: salesforce-cdp

I am trying to connect my Salesforce Dev Environment using DBeaver Salesforce CDP Connection.

Despite giving all the details correctly, it shows the error message "end-user denied authorization". Anyone faced similar issue?

**DBeaver Salesforce CDP Connection details:**

Username : myusername

Password : mypassword+security_token

Driver Properties : clientid and privatekey from ConnectedApp

Org is not MFA Enabled.

[image]

**Connected App:**

[image]

Permitted Users:    **All users may self-authorize**
IP Relaxation : **Relax IP restrictions**

Comment: Have you checked with the vendor's support?

Comment: @DavidCheng - Not yet, I thought this might be an issue on my side with SF Configurations.